# Assigning colors to HTML table columns based on conditions

Tags: html, linux, bash, shell

I am using a bash script to send an email in `html table` format.

I have a command like below.

Columns are:

```
table1_amount
table1_count
table2_amount
table2_count
count_validation
amount_validation
```

scenario:

> When counts are matching then count_validation column will have 'Matching' with green color background else red color background. Same way for amounts.

What am I missing or doing wrong in my code?

Using the below statement I am able to do for count_validation but not for amount_validation column.

```
awk -F"#" 'BEGIN{print "<style> body { background-color: #FFF;text-align:left; } table { font-family:Tahoma;font-size:11;border-collapse:collapse; border: 4px solid #dddddd;} th { padding:10px;background-color: #94E1F7; } th { border: 1px solid black; } td { padding:3px;border: 2px solid black;text-align:right; } </style></head><body><table>  <tr> <th>table1_count</th> <th>table1_amount</th> <th>table2_count</th> <th>table2_amount</th> <th>count_validation</th> <th>amount_validation</th></tr>"} {print "<tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (i=="5"){ if ($i=="Matching") {print "<td bgcolor='#4dffa6' >" $i"</td>"} else {print "<td bgcolor='red'>" $i"</td>"} elif (i=="6"){ if ($i=="Matching") {print "<td bgcolor='green' >" $i"</td>"} else {print "<td bgcolor='red'>" $i"</td>"}} else {print "<td>" $i "</td>"} ;print "</tr>"} END{print "</table>"}' ${tmp_dir}/QC_VALIDATION_REPORT.txt >> ${tmp_dir}/QC_VALIDATION_REPORT.html
```

> > awk -F"#" 'BEGIN{print " body { background-color: #FFF;text-align:left; } table { font-family:Tahoma;font-size:11;border-collapse:collapse; border: 4px solid #dddddd;} th { padding:10px;background-color: #94E1F7; } th { border: 1px solid black; } td { padding:3px;border: 2px solid black;text-align:right; }    table1_count table1_amount table2_count table2_amount count_validation amount_validation"} {print "";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (i=="5"){ if ($i=="Matching") {print "" $i""} else {print "" $i""} elif (i=="6"){ if ($i=="Matching") {print "" $i""} else {print "" $i""}} else {print "" $i ""} ;print ""} END{print ""}' ${run_project_tmp_dir}/QC_VALIDATION_REPORT.txt >> ${tmp_dir}/QC_VALIDATION_REPORT.html

`Dummy data`

```
718#394682876.71#718#394682876.71#Matching#Matching
30956#6637761.58#30956#6637760.58#Matching#Not_Matching
```

Comment: Is your awk command really a single line like that? I would be a lot easier to read if you could split it over multiple lines. I edited the rest of your post for legibility, but I didn't want to edit the `awk` line in case I'd break it, but if you can edit it to put it on multiple lines, it will help readers understand your question. You might also want to show the output it produces and the output you would like instead, to help us further understand.

Comment: I don't think that there is `elif` in awk.

Comment: @Samha' I have added the `elif` but this one doesn't give me correct result

Comment: And there is a closing `</head>` tag and an opening `<body>`, is that ok?

Comment: and will u please add a sample file with dummy data to correctly testing this?

Comment: @Samha' Added sample data to test

Comment: If my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark.

Comment: I've updated my answer, pls take note of the little but important change in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code with the dummy data you provided as a simple test:

```
data="718#394682876.71#718#394682876.71#Matching#Matching
30956#6637761.58#30956#6637760.58#Matching#Not_Matching"


awk -F"#" '
  BEGIN {
    print "<html><head>\
      <style>\
        body {\
          background-color: #FFF;text-align:left;\
        }\
        table {\
          font-family:Tahoma;\
          font-size:11;\
          border-collapse:collapse;\
          border: 4px solid #dddddd;\
        }\
        th { padding:10px;\
          background-color: #94E1F7;\
        }\
        th {\
          border: 1px solid black;\
        }\
        td {\
          padding:3px;\
          border: 2px solid black;\
          text-align:right;\
        }\
      </style>\
    </head>\
    <body>\
      <table>\
        <tr>\
          <th>table1_count</th>\
          <th>table1_amount</th>\
          <th>table2_count</th>\
          <th>table2_amount</th>\
          <th>count_validation</th>\
          <th>amount_validation</th>\
        </tr>"
  }
  {
    print "<tr>"
    printf "<td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td>",$1,$2,$3,$4
    for (i = 5; i < 7; i++) {
      if ($i == "Matching") {
        printf "<td bgcolor=\"green\">%s</td>",$i
      } else {
        printf "<td bgcolor=\"red\">%s</td>",$i
      }
    }
    print "</tr>"
  }
  END {
    print "</table></body></html>"
  }
' <(echo "$data") > ./test.html
```

And here, some notes on your posted code:

1. `elif` isn't valid in `awk`, nor `else if`, if you really need this, you'll have to **nest `if` conditions**.
2. **preserve indentation**, it really helps in terms of **readability** which is considered the most important aspect of **clean code**.
3. **avoid nesting conditionals** as much as you can. More than *2-levels* is bad.

Comment: Worked as a charm. This is what I was looking for